# What does @ mean in Scala?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, partialfunction

When studying sources of `akka` I found the following in the `akka.event.slf4j.SLF4JLogger` actor:

```
def receive = {
    //...
    case event @ Warning(logSource, logClass, message) ⇒
      withMdc(logSource, event) { Logger(logClass, logSource).warn("{}", message.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]) }

    case event @ Info(logSource, logClass, message) ⇒
      withMdc(logSource, event) { Logger(logClass, logSource).info("{}", message.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]) }

    case event @ Debug(logSource, logClass, message) ⇒
      withMdc(logSource, event) { Logger(logClass, logSource).debug("{}", message.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]) }
    //...
}
```

I didn't quite understand what is the `@` sign. It was not a method and there's no declaration of the `event` in scope. `Warning`, `Info` and `Debug` are all objects with apply methods.

Comment: @c1moore oh, that's right, didnt find related answer

Answer (score 2):

It's called variable binding:

> In addition to the standalone variable patterns, you can also add a
>   variable to any other pattern. You simply write the variable name, an
>   at sign (@), and then the pattern. This gives you a variable-binding
>   pattern. The meaning of such a pattern is to perform the pattern match
>   as normal, and if the pattern succeeds, set the variable to the
>   matched object just as with a simple variable pattern.

http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/case-classes-and-pattern-matching.html